# pandas: lambda function to replace value of df column when multiple conditions are met

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, feature-engineering

I have to replace certain values of one column if it matches a value from another column.

df example:

```
column_1 column_2

    X       yes
    X       yes
    Y       yes
    X       yes
    Y       NaN
```

lambda function I'm trying to apply to replace 'yes' on column_2 with NaN if column_1 == 'Y'

```
df.column_2.apply(lambda x: x.replace('yes',np.NaN) if ((df.column_2 == 'yes') & (df.column_1 == 'Y')) else x)
```

I'm getting this error

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: df.apply(lambda x: x["column_2"].replace('yes',"") if ((x["column_2"] == 'yes') & (x["column_1"] == 'Y')) else x, axis=1), its mixed working with rows and then columns (series), by using apply and axis=1, you have the info of the row to work with, replacing np.nan with empty string since error was appearing.

Comment: That worked like a charm! thank you so much!